# 12.10 Booting Into Variations Of Blank Screen

Tags: boot, 12.10, screen, text-mode

I've been running the Ubuntu 12.10 beta since about a month before the final release with almost no problems. However since the day of release (I'm assuming an update has caused this) I have had problems booting into the actual GUI interface. Trying to get it to work is just a case of hard shutting down until it works, but for most of the time I need to battle with various different kinds of black screens. These include a plain black screen, a flashing line and a flashing line that doesn't fit the resolution. Nine times out of ten the cursor will be displayed over these. It also sometimes manages to boot into Ubuntu, albeit text mode or sometimes it loads GRUB which it isn't setup to do.

If anyone could help out with this it'd be great. I really, *really* don't want to have to go through yet another clean installation. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I just clean installed 12.10 with updates during install and anything other that the default nouveau driver results in problems (nvidia based card). The nouveau driver also has a problem.

So yes, either they need send out updates that fix it or you do what I did and go back to 12.04. 12.10 is problem city atm.